# finder is slow, disk access is slow, 1.5 million files on disk

Tags: finder

Folders take seconds to respond; Activity monitor shows nothing; there are 1.5 million files on the computer. Is the Finder overloaded?

Comment: Let's see if anyone has a ready answer. If not, we can help you edit your question to provide more details on what you've tried, what exactly you don't get. See the guides on [about] and [ask] if you don't get an answer and decide to edit your question. They are often helpful in refining / reframing your query.

Comment: More to the topic: Unless all the 1.5 million files are in the same folder, they *shouldn't* have an impact on Finder performance. To analyze further: Reboot, check whether all user accounts show the same problem, give us some details about other apps/menulets which are running, tell us about your HW setup (local disks/external disks).

Answer (score 1):

How much space is left on your harddrive?

Alway try te keep 15% free space. If for example you have 500GB, and you already use 470GB, this will usually seriously slow down your mac, there should at least be 75GB of free space.

*More info: http://macs.about.com/od/faq1/f/How-Much-Free-Drive-Space-Do-I-Need.htm*

Answer (score 0):

You can try [resetting the LaunchServices database](http://furbo.org/2013/04/22/launch-services-woes/) by running `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed -r` in Terminal. It's been known to bog down Finder at times.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by starting up in Safe Mode (Safe Boot)
I opened all the folders that were slow in finder. The first 2 or 3 of them were still slow. Then they started to open really fast. Did nothing more. Restarted my machine & then everything was great.

---

Starting up in Safe Mode
To start up into Safe Mode (to Safe Boot), follow these steps.

Be sure your Mac is shut down.
Press the power button.
Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold the Shift key. 
The Shift key should be held as soon as possible after the startup tone, but not before the tone.
Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple logo and the progress indicator (looks like a spinning gear).
After the logo appears, you should see a progress bar during startup. This indicates that your computer is performing a directory check as part of Safe Mode.

To leave Safe Mode, restart your computer without holding any keys during startup.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Be sure to quote your sources as it appears you wrote this when much of the final paragraphs are lifted verbatim from Apple's KB article.

Answer (score -3):

Get a external drive, and clean your mac.
Also i heard mac keeper is similiar to ccleaner in that it cleans your mac and keeps it running smooth

Clean and Optimize!